# How to append modal created in iFrame to parent window with different domains with Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to append a modal which is sitting in an iFrame to the parent which contains the iFrame. The tricky part is that they are violating the cross origin policies due to different domains.

I was already able to bypass that and adapt the iFrame height by using `postMessage()` in Javascript:

```
let currentContentHeight = $('html').height();
window.parent.postMessage(currentContentHeight, '*');
```

And then listen in the parent for that event and change the iFrame height accordingly.

Is there a way to achieve the same with the modal? As soon as the modal is opened I could fire a `postMessage()` event.

The question is which information I have to append to achieve that the modal is appended to the parent `html`?

Or is it possible to change the iFrame so that it is filling 100% of the page height and width?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by sending an information to the parent with `postMessage()` when the modal is opened in the iFrame and when it is closed.

(Child) On open:

```
window.parent.postMessage('modal-open');
```

(Child) On close:

```
window.parent.postMessage('modal-close');
```

(Child) On initialize (when the component in iFrame is loaded for the first time):

```
var currentContentHeight = $('html').height();
window.parent.postMessage(currentContentHeight);
```

(Parent) When the parent receives the message the iFrame style is adjusted to occupy full screen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var childHtmlHeight = '';
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 
    if (~event.origin.indexOf('http://child-page.com')) { 
        if (event.data === 'modal-open') {
            // Event modal open is triggered so adjust the stlye of the iframe to full screen
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.position = 'fixed';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.top = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.bottom = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.right = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.left = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.width = '100% !important';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.height = '100% !important';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.border = 'none';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.margin = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.padding = 0;
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.overflow = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.zindex = 999999;
        } else {
            // Event initialization or close is triggered so adjust the stlye of the iframe back and set height to iframe's <html> height
            if (childHtmlHeight === '') {
                childHtmlHeight = event.data;
            }

            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.position = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.top = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.bottom = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.right = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.left = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.border = 'none';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.margin = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.padding = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.overflow = 'auto';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.zindex = 'unset';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').style.height = childHtmlHeight + 'px !important';
            document.getElementById('my-iframe').height = childHtmlHeight;
        }
    } else { 
        // The data hasn't been sent from origin domain 
        return; 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```